# Lumen Framework Env routes depend enviroment

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to configure my Lumen application.

I want to add a different route depending on the current APP_ENV.

For example, if the APP_ENV is set to production (APP_ENV=production) I want to add the route `www.domain.com/pro/...`

```
If APP_ENV=QA -> www.domain.com/qa

If APP_ENV=local -> www.domain.com/local...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a redirect in the route:

```
$app->get('/my-route', function ()  {
    switch (App::environment()) {
        case "local":
            return redirect->to('http://www.domain.com/local');
        case "QA":
            return redirect->to('http://www.domain.com/qa');
    }
    return redirect->to('http://www.domain.com/production');
    // or just:
    // return redirect->to("http://www.domain.com/" . strtolower(App::environment));
});
```

Comment: Excelent! Works fine.
Other question, its posible to change the public name from url?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If my answer helped you, could you please upvote or accept it?

Comment: You know, to access to a services in lumen, the normal ulr is for example http://localhost/lumen/public/services. I wanna change the 'public' for other word

Comment: Actually, the normal url is `localhost/services` -- the word `public` shouldn't be in the URL if you have apache/nginx configured correctly. See http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#basic-configuration

Comment: In localhost I need to add 'public' to access the services. Its posible to change in localhost?